# Prove that $f(a)f(b)<0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ a continous and differentiable function such that $f''(x)>0$ and $F$ is primitive. Prove that this equation
$$\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}-\frac{F(x)-F(b)}{x-b}+\frac{1}{2}(b-a)f'(x)=0.$$
has at least one solution
I know from the propriety of Darboux that I can solve the problem by proving $f(a)f(b)<0$ but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: Is $F$ supposed to be an antiderivative for $f$?

Comment: I don't think you could prove that $f(a)f(b)<0$, since maybe $f$ is positive everywhere. For example, $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: Yes @alex.jordan F is the antiderivate of f.

Comment: Then what can I do to solve this problem?@alex.jordan